# Duplicate File Creating in Android 8.0

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-8.0-oreo

I have an Sqlite ".S3db" File in Android Device.Yesterday I have updated Android 8.0 Version in my Device.After upgrading 8.0 The Sqlite file showing as twice in same directory.It create two files First once is ".S3db" and second once is **".s3db"**  (Case Sensitive).

Is there any bugs in "Android 8.0" ???

Comment: no its not a bug, and they are two different files.

Comment: The First FileName  is "Diary.S3db" and Second File Name is "Diary.s3db"

Comment: According to ASCII value, they are two different text, that's what I am saying. In lunix base system like Android, file system is case sensitive.

Comment: Ok Noted, there are Five tables in "Diary.S3db",When I view this Database File in SQliteExplorer,no table is showing after restart the device all five tables is showing....